# Check the child checkboxes onclick of parent checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an html code where there are  two parent checkboxes and their children respectively. Onclick of parent checkbox the children belonging to that parent should be checked. In my case , if I check a parent checkbox all child  checkboxes are selected. I know its the problem with the classname I can name with two different class names and solve the problem. But i cannot change the classnames. It should be the same. how do I fix this??

**index.html**

```
        Parent1<input name="parent" class="pc-box" type="checkbox">
        Child 1<input class="check" name="child" type="checkbox">
        Child 2<input class="check" name="child" type="checkbox">
        Child 3<input class="check" name="child" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        Parent2<input name="parent" class="pc-box" type="checkbox" >
        Child 1 <input class="check" name="child" type="checkbox">
        Child 2 <input class="check" name="child" type="checkbox">
        Child 3 <input class="check" name="child" type="checkbox">
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".pc-box").click(function() {
if (this.checked) {
       ('.check').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
    }

 });
   });
```

[here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk23Q/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nextUntil` to get the child checkboxes following the parent. If you remove the `if` statement you can also make the parent in to a toggle.

```
$('.pc-box').change(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.pc-box').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')); 
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/QDLBr/)

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the jquery selector while setting the checkbox value in condition.  also you need to modify the selector to target only the elements before next `.pc-box` checkbox which acts as parent. Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".pc-box").click(function() {
 if (this.checked) {
   $(this).nextUntil('.pc-box').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
 }
});});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjs2e/)**

Comment: Your answers are always on point, lil explanation will be helpful to others and even to the OP, will act like cherry on the ice cream :)